# Как возвращать значение из then?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно использовать несколько функций, возвращающих Promise. Так вот, как мне возвращать результат выполнения этих функций?

```
function GetProp() {
    var val;
    MyFunc().then(function(value) {
        val = value;
    }).then(function () {
        //return val;
    });
    return val;
}
```

Может можно ждать получение значения?

Comment: При помощи такого же Promise. Promise — это асинхронный объект. Если делаешь в браузере, подождать пока Promise получит результат и вернуть его в синхронной функции без кривых костылей нельзя. Если делаешь на node.js, используй deasync https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz Да, на node.js, Electron. К сожалению deasync выдает ошибку.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz А Promise я вернуть не могу, поскольку возвращаемое значение сразу передается в чужой модуль.

Comment: Тогда ищи другие решения, без Promise

Comment: А, не прочитал, что всё таки на ноде. Тогда есть шанс. Что за ошибка?

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz Добавил текст ошибки в этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607062/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-electron