# В чем можно хранить данные в приложении Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Мне нужно быстро сохранять и получать данные из хранилища. На данный момент я хочу использовать [electron-json-storage](https://github.com/jviotti/electron-json-storage#module_storage.remove).

Вот так на данный момент выглядит функция возврата значения по ключу:

```
get: function(key) {
    var value;
    var done = false;
    storage.get(key, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Get.Err. "+key+" : "+error);
        }
        console.log("Get "+key+" : "+data.Key+" - "+data.Key.pubKey);
        value = data.Key;
        done = true;
    });
    //require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return !done;});
    return value;
}
```

Однако из-за того, что результат не возвращается напрямую, функция `get` возвращает `undefined`.

Я хотел использовать модуль `deasync`, но тогда выскакивает ошибка как [тут](https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/58). Я думал об использовании [electron-config](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-config), только там я не смог сохранить и получить обратно `ArrayBuffer`.

Что делать? Может использовать локальную БД?

**Обновление**

Возвращать Promise или принимать колбеки я не могу, поскольку эта функция возвращает значение модулю, который я изменить не могу.

**Обновление №2**

Я пытался использовать deasync. При использовании выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\build\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\build\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\build\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\out\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\out\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\build\default\deasync.node
 → C:\path\src\node_modules\deasync\compiled\6.5.0\win32\x64\deasync.node
```

Способ исправления этого я не нашел.

Comment: используйте **Promice** и возвращайте его, как результат `get` или пусть ваш `get`, тоже принимает колбэк

Comment: @Sublihim возвращать Promise я не могу, поскольку эта функция вызывается из стороннего модуля, который я изменить не могу.

Comment: тогда, не завесив процесс выполнения ноды, на время ответа от базы - никак. Или пилите `deasync` пока не запустите

Comment: @Sublihim Ох и неудобен этот язык...

Comment: Язык тут не причем, это такая асинхронная архитектура, как-раз, кстати, и сделана для того, чтобы все выполнялось быстро, не "завешивая", всю ноду или браузер. Но, для этого надо изменить сознание, да. ) И асинхронность - это уже современный тренд многих ЯП, даже, кажется в последних стандартах С++ добавили аналоги промайсов

Comment: @Sublihim **промизов**. Раз уж вы замахнулись на соблюдение английского произношения.

Comment: прям на Вильяма,понимаете ли, нашего Шекспира замахнулся ) Теперь так и буду ходить, опозоренный )

Comment: заверни в `async` и `await`

Comment: @D-side если и вы замахнулись на него, то /ˈpɹɒmɪs/ без всяких **з**)

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz "промисы" и "промизы" в английском произношении хотя бы легко спутать. Но уж никак не "промисы" и "промайсы" :) Так-то "промисы" правильнее, хотя [в этом направлении в языке какой-то адъ творится](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/pronunciation-of-ise-in-verbs-and-nouns/).

Comment: @Sublihim Я ничего не имею против асинхронности. Меня просто расстраивает то, что тут нет await.

Comment: *"Возвращать Promise или принимать колбеки я не могу, поскольку эта функция возвращает значение модулю, который я изменить не могу."* - а что это за хитрый модуль такой?

Answer (score 1):

Делай так

```
// Зависимость deasync
const deasync = require('deasync');

// ....

get: function(key) {
    var value;

    storage.get(key, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Get.Err. "+key+" : "+error);
        }
        console.log("Get "+key+" : "+data.Key+" - "+data.Key.pubKey);

        value = data.Key;
    });

    // Держим код на месте, пока не получена переменная
    while(value === undefined)
        deasync.runLoopOnce();

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Я пытался использовать deasync. Результат я добавлю в вопрос.